# How to set focus on the minimum date in datepickerdialog android?

Tags: android, datepickerdialog

After setting the minimum and maximum date in DatePickerDialog, not able to set focus on minimum date.

```
final DatePickerDialog datePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(Test.this, new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
  @Override
  public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {   
  }
}, mYear, mMonth, mDay);
Calendar max= Calendar.getInstance();
max.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 4);

datePickerDialog.getDatePicker().setMinDate(System.currentTimeMillis());
datePickerDialog.getDatePicker().setMaxDate(max.getTimeInMillis());
datePickerDialog.show();`
```

Comment: what you try so far post your code here.

Answer (score 0):

This is the code to set today as minimum date and maximum date is after 4 years .
Before today and after 4 years you will not able to select the date.

```
public class DateActivity extends Activity {

TextView tvDatePicker;
Calendar cal,cal1;
long maxDate;
Date date;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal1 = Calendar.getInstance();

    tvDatePicker = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtDatePicker);
    tvDatePicker.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            DatePickerDialog dialog = new DatePickerDialog(MainActivity.this, new OnDateSetListener() {

                @Override
                public void onDateSet(DatePicker arg0, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {

                }
        }, cal.YEAR, cal.MONTH, cal.DAY_OF_MONTH);
        dialog.getDatePicker().setMinDate(System.currentTimeMillis());
        cal1.add(Calendar.YEAR, 4);
        dialog.getDatePicker().setMaxDate(cal1.getTimeInMillis());
        dialog.show();
    }
});
}
```